# Hide add to cart button based on custom field value - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

In content-product.php, products from the current category page have a "add to cart"-button if the item has a price.

I want to remove this button, BUT only on the items that returns true on the if statement around it.

I tried:

```
$showBuyButtonNo = get_field('show_buy_button');
    if ($showBuyButtonNo) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
```

BUT this does it to all items.

Comment: How will you decide which  product will have the add to cart option?

Comment: if the product does not have true in the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update default WooCommerce **content-product.php** as below:

[image: Screenshot of code]

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
  // replace a_category and another_category with the slugs of the categories you'd like to have the button removed from
  if( is_product_category( array( 'a_category', 'another_category'))) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.wpblog.com/add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store/
Reference: https://gist.github.com/rynaldos/560c621714b9680433cddf18e6a50305